# Discord Bot pin message

Tags: python, documentation, discord, discord.py

Im kinda new to discord bot and python so I am running into a little trouble understanding where I am going wrong. Basically I want to get my bot to pin a message. I found a documentation for python code which says to use pin_message() so i have:

```
if "pinm()" == message.content.lower():
   #to pin a message
   message.channel.pin_message(messageID)
```

but i get the following error AttributeError: 'TextChannel' object has no attribute 'pin_message'

When I look at the Discord documentation it says
PUT /channels/{channel.id}/pins/{message.id}
I dont really understand how to translate this down to code so i have something like this:

```
    if "pinm()" == message.content.lower():
        #to pin a message
        allPins = message.channel.pins(messageID)
```

but i get the error pins() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given.
The sources i am following are

https://discordapp.com/developers/docs/resources/channel#add-pinned-channel-message

https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#message

Can anyone tell me where I am going wrong with this? :(

Comment: According to the [documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=pin#discord.Client.pin_message) it should be `await client.pin_message(message)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: You're actually using [discord.py-rewrite](/questions/tagged/discord.py-rewrite), so you need to do

```
msg_to_pin = await message.channel.get_message(int(messageID))
await msg_to_pin.pin()
```

Original:

You need to use the [`Client.pin_message`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client.pin_message), passing a `Message` object (not the id).  You frequently already have the message object, but otherwise you'll have to use `Client.get_message`, which requires you to also know the channel the message is in.

```
msg_to_pin = await client.get_message(message.channel, messageID)
await client.pin_message(msg_to_pin)
```

Make sure your bot has the `manage_messages` permission, or this will fail.

Comment: Hey there, so i have used your response but i am still getting errors when I run the code: AttributeError: 'Client' object has no attribute 'get_message'
But if I use await message.channel.get_message(ID) it seems to work but then the same error appears for client.pin_message(msg_to_pin)

I doubled checked to make sure that manage_permission is on as well. :/ I don't understand where I am going wrong as your solution makes sense and should work :/

Comment: Try running `print(discord.__version__)` If the version is `1.0` or greater, you're using the not fully official pre-release rewrite branch.   That's a good thing, but you do need to read the appropriate documentation, as there have been many important changes: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/rewrite/index.html

Comment: @Patrcik you're a life saver thank you it worked!! :D
So i should keep using message.channel. from now on instead of client.